# Link to external m file from Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulink model which relies on a piece of code which relies on several libraries. The embedded MATLAB function is not very useful because of that. Is there a way to have the simulation run and take input from an m file which is not in the simulation? I have done some searching for it but have not found anything useful. Answers or locations for answers would be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a Matlab s function?

Comment: @Daniel understand that I can use those, and I will probably have to if it's the only option, but I'd like to be able to link to an external m file and take input from there inside the simulation.

Comment: If it's just for defining the inputs (data) for the model, then I would suggest using a model callback, probably `PreLoadFcn`. See [Model callbacks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/model-callbacks.html) in the doc for more details.